# If a sequence ${a_n}$ is monotonically increasing. then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \sup{(a_n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

Can you please tell me if my proof is correct:

> If a sequence ${a_n}$ is monotonically increasing. Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \sup{(a_n)}$$

*Proof:*
$$a_n\leq a_{n+1}\leq \sup(a_n)$$
Assume for the sake of contradiction that $$|a_n-sup(a_n)|>\epsilon$$
$$a_n-\sup(a_n)>\epsilon$$
$$a_n>\epsilon+\sup(a_n)$$ !!contradiction with definition of supremum
Hence, $$|a_n-\sup(a_n)| \leq \epsilon$$
 which implies
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \sup{(a_n)}$$

Comment: "A <= B <= C" is a short from to "A <= B and B <= C". Then the negation is "A > B or B > C". You  need to prove when "A > B" and when "B > C" lead a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is incomplete. When you assume by contradiction of $|a_n−\sup(a_n)|\le\epsilon$, i.e., $-\epsilon\le a_n-\sup(a_n)\;\;\text{and}\;\;a_n-\sup(a_n)\le\epsilon$, the negation is $-\epsilon> a_n-\sup(a_n)\;\;\text{or}\;\;a_n-\sup(a_n)>\epsilon$. So you need to prove two cases.

---

*Proof.* Let $\epsilon>0$ be a positive real number and let $x:=\sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$. Since $x-\epsilon<x$, by Lemma 1, there exists a integer $m'$ such that $x-\epsilon<a_{m'}\le x$, i.e., $x-\epsilon<a_{m'}<x+\epsilon$. Also, since $a_n \le a_{n+1}$ for every $n$; we can show by induction (using base case $m'$) that $x-\epsilon<a_n<x+\epsilon$ for every $n\ge m'$, i.e., $-\epsilon<a_n-x<\epsilon$ for every $n\ge m'$. Thus we have $|a_n-x|<\epsilon$ for ervery $n\ge m'$. By Lemma 2, $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to $x$.

**NOTE**. The Lemma 2 is subtle. But I do not know with what premises you are working.

> **Lemma 1.** Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers, and let $x:=\sup(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$. Then for every real number $y$ for which $y<x$, there exists at least one $n\ge m$ for which $y<a_n\le x$.
>
> **Lemma 2.**  Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers, let $L$ be areal number, and let $m'\ge m$ be an integer. Then $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ converges to $L$ if and only if $(a_n)_{n=m'}^\infty$ converges to $L$.